# Unity, How To SetPixels32 Properly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, pixel, webcam

I'm receiving the error ***SetPixels32 called with invalid number of pixels in the array UnityEngine.Texture2D:SetPixels32(Color32[])*** on a line of code that is trying to retrieve a pixel array.

In some instances I receive the error but in others the webcams stream just fine. I'm not sure why this is occurring. This is the line of code that is giving me problems:

***streamTexture.SetPixels32(webcamTexture.GetPixels32(pixels))***

That isn't much to go on, however, below is the full script. If Anyone can tell me why this error is occurring since the streaming texture is set to the dimensions of the webcam texture. Any help is much appreciated!

```
 using System.Collections;
 using UnityEngine;
 using Photon.Pun;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 
 public class WebcamStream : MonoBehaviourPun, IPunObservable
 {
     [SerializeField] private LocalPlayerSettings playerSettings;
     [SerializeField] private AvatarHandler parent;
     [SerializeField] private RawImage streamRawimage;


 private WebCamTexture webcamTexture;
 private Texture2D streamTexture;
 private Color32[] pixels;
 private byte[] data;

 private void OnEnable()
 {
     if (!parent.photonView.IsMine)
         return;

     InitWebcam();
 }

 private void OnDisable()
 {
     if (!parent.photonView.IsMine)
         return;

     webcamTexture.Stop();
 }

 private void InitWebcam()
 {
     //cast dimensions of target UI as ints for new webcam texture
     int width = (int)streamRawimage.rectTransform.rect.width;
     int height = (int)streamRawimage.rectTransform.rect.height;

     //set new dimensions and target device
     webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture(width, height)
     {
         deviceName = playerSettings.Webcam
     };

     //display webcam texture on the raw image and start camera
     streamRawimage.material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;
     webcamTexture.Play();

     //set pixels and stream texture to match webcamTexture
     pixels = new Color32[webcamTexture.width * webcamTexture.height];
     streamTexture = new Texture2D(webcamTexture.width, webcamTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

     //Begin Streaming Webcam Data
     StartCoroutine(StreamWebcam());
 }

 private IEnumerator StreamWebcam()
 {
     while (webcamTexture.deviceName == playerSettings.Webcam)
     {
         if (webcamTexture.isPlaying)
         {
             //set the target texture pixels to the webcam texture pixels and apply get/set
             streamTexture.SetPixels32(webcamTexture.GetPixels32(pixels));
             streamTexture.Apply();

             //convert image to byte array
             data = streamTexture.EncodeToJPG();
         }

         yield return null;
     }

     webcamTexture.Stop();

     if(WebCamTexture.devices.Length > 0)
     {
         InitWebcam();
     }
 }

 public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
 {
     if (stream.IsWriting)
     {
         //send the byte array through the stream
         stream.SendNext(data);
     }
     else
     {
         //convert object received into byte array via cast
         data = (byte[])stream.ReceiveNext();

         //create new texture to load received data into
         streamTexture = new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
         streamTexture.LoadImage(data);

         //set webcam raw image texture to the newly updated texture
         streamRawimage.texture = streamTexture;
     }
 }
```

}

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that maybe the webcam or stream textures aren't ready/initialised yet. Maybe add a yield (a null or a wait) to the very start of ```StreamWebcam()``` and see if that helps.

Comment: @Immersive Thanks for the idea, however, it didn't seem to do the trick :( I added a fairly long wait with **yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);**

Answer (score 0):

Solved! There was another script responsible for enabling this scripts game object and needed a yield for about 1 second.

Also a quick edit of `streamRawimage.material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;` to `streamRawimage.texture = webcamTexture;` fixed another issue surrounding a missing texture.